# OpenSocial gadget email client support?

Tags: xml, email, embed, content-type, opensocial

I'm considering using OpenSocial gadgets in email but haven't been able to find any references on email client support for Content-Type application/embed+{xml | json}.

Anyone know of a good, recent reference for this information?

Answer (score 0):

IBM has announced this its mail clients will be supporting embedding OpenSocial gadgets in emails in their next releases (embedded experiences).  This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7yby_IJqgY) from Lotusphere 2012 shows several business partners demonstrating some of the integration they have done by embedding gadgets in emails.  Keep in mind you can also embedded gadgets in activity streams, which IBM and Jive will also be supporting.  Let me know if you have any other questions.